# What proportion of visitors to SE sites are logged in?

Tags: discussion, users, traffic

I'm interested in this for no other reason than idle curiosity. Is there any way to find out:

- What proportion of activity (questions/answers) comes from logged in users?
- What proportion of traffic comes from logged in users?

Obviously the figure will be very high for the first one, though I'd be interested to know how high.

For the second question I would imagine there is a lot of not-logged-in traffic coming through, but, relative to the number of unique visitors, the traffic for logged in users would be a lot higher. i.e. the average logged in user views a lot more pages than the average not-logged-in user.