# Can I parse out the number of unregistered or not logged-in users from Quantcast stats?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, unregistered-users

Can I parse out the number of unregistered or not logged-in users from Quantcast stats? If yes, how?

I am looking at the [SE page on Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com) but couldn't find any related feature.

The OP of [What proportion of visitors to SE sites are logged in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103828) wondered about the same thing but he didn't get any answer so I am asking again.